# How to stop child component re-rendering on parent state change?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state, console.log

I have `400` textfield in `App.tsx`. Textfield code is present in child component `textfield.tsx`
When I change textfield state from my parent component my child re renders 400 times

I want `hi` in console to print only `1` time instead of `400`.
How can I solve this issue?

**Sample Code:**

**App.ts**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import MyTextField from "./components/textField.tsx/textField";

function App() {
   const [state, setState] = useState({} as any);
   const arr: any[] = []

   const fn = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
     arr.push(i)
    }
   }
   function onChange(event: any) {
     const { name, value } = event.target;
     setState((prevState: any) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
   }
    return (
    <>
      {fn()}
      {
        arr.map((e) => <MyTextField variant='outlined' name={'n' + e} value={state['n'+ e]} onChange={onChange} />)
        }
    </>
   );

  }
 export default App;
```

**textField.tsx**

```
import { TextField, TextFieldProps, } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";

const myClasses = ["custom1", "subvariant-hovered"] as const

type Props = Omit<TextFieldProps, "className" | "variant"> & {
  variant:  typeof myClasses[number] | TextFieldProps["variant"];
};

function MyTextField({ variant,name, ...rest }: Props) {
  return (
  <>
    {console.log('hi')}
     {myClasses.includes(variant as typeof ivpClasses[number]) ? (
       <TextField label="Search"  className={variant} {...rest}></TextField>
       ) : (
      <TextField label="Search" variant={variant as TextFieldProps["variant"]{...rest</TextField>
    )}
   </>
  )
 }
 export default React.memo(MyTextField);
```

**Issue**
As soon as I enter `w` one time console.log print `hi` `400` times. I want hi to print only `1` time for each character.

[On changing state of one text field console.log print hi 400 times for each character we typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k812w.png)

**Code Sandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-issue-m3i82e?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: It's your App that re-renders and causing the input to re-render as well. Every time you change value, App is re-rendered, which causing the arr variable to be recreated and fn() to be called again. Which means it would render 400 new TextFelds. Move arr and fn outside of the app and it should solve the problem

Comment: @szczocik I hardcoded arr values eg. arr=[1,2,3,4] and removed fn() call from my code also. Now my screen has only 4 textfield. Now also when I enter single char any of text field my console print hi 4 times. I need way to print hi only one time. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so the issue is going deeper than what I have mentioned in my comment. It was true as well: for every re-render you were recreating the array and calling the function to populate it, which was causing the issue.

Additionally, your component state is an object that you append values to. Remember, when the state changes, it will re-render all the components that are hooked up to that state. And with every re-render it creates a new object, causing all of the inputs to re-render.

In order to sort this out, you could take a look at [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) function as a wrapper around your state and for rendering your TextInput. I've created a sample here, which seems to be giving the output you want.

https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-issue-forked-490ki2?file=/src/myTextField/myTextField.tsx

Comment: I need to add def value also in some text field but issue is once I add add default value in useState my state update doesn't reflect in my textfield as dependency array is empty . But if I mention my state in dependency array all 100 text field render again. Please check code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-issue-m3i82e?file=/src/App.tsx